# Use SIMPLE javascript to confirm deletion in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I know there are other versions of this question but I am posting this question as none of them provide exactly what I want.

All I want is

- User clicks 'Delete'
- User gets JS Confirm dialog

  - if YES

    - Proceed with deletion
  - if NO

    - Do nothing

I am using Django's generic DeleteView

```
class CommentDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    success_url = 'index.html'
    template_name = 'index.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CommentDelete, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(CommentDelete, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        if not obj.owner == self.request.user:
            raise Http404
        return obj
```

My delete button looks like the following

```
<h2><a href="comment/{{ cmt.id }}/delete" class="cmt_del">
    Delete
</a></h2>
```

--EDIT--
I managed to get the dialog up but do not know what to do next.

How would I delete a specific comment when I click "yes" in confirm dialog?

Answer (score 2):

What about adding a custom data-attribute for easy access?

```
[HTML]
<a href="comment/{{ cmt.id }}/delete" class="cmt_del" data-confirm="true">
    Delete
</a>

[jQuery]
$('*[data-confirm="true"]').on('click', function() {
    return confirm("Are you sure?");
});
```

Comment: If the dialog returns false, the post action will be prevented.

Comment: OK this works now. However, After I click ok and get taken to my index page, the comment is not deleted.. any guess? (btw I changed response = ... in dispatch method to return ...)

Answer (score 1):

You should prevent default action on button click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cmt_del').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var a = confirm('Sure?');
        if(a){}
        else if(!a){}
    });
});
```